# Facebook login freezes app and doesn't open the facebook permission view on iOS 13

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api

Issue logging with facebook. The app freezes after tapping continue and cannot open the facebook permission view. No errors.

It is working fine on older iOS versions. I think the issue is from the new iOS page sheet. Tried to `viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` but not working too.

The `UIViewController` is embedded in a `UINavigationViewController` tried to make is full screen too but useless. Any tips that could help?

> FBSDK version 5.11.0 & iOS 13.1.3

Here is a video with the freeze happening. [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oT4i8Es0cdI&feature=youtu.be)

```
func loginWithFacebookWithDelegate(_  delegate: OperationDelegate?,viewController:UIViewController){

        LoginManager().logIn(permissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: viewController) { (result, error) in

            if(error != nil){
                delegate?.didRecieveErrorForOperation(.FBLogin, andWithError: error)
                return
            }else{
                LoadingView.sharedInstance.show()
                let parameters = //["fields":"email,picture.type(large),gender,first_name,last_name,age_range"]
                    ["fields":"id,email,picture.type(large),gender,name,age_range"]
                GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
                    LoadingView.sharedInstance.hide()
                    if(error != nil){
                        delegate?.didRecieveErrorForOperation(.FBLogin, andWithError: error)
                        return
                    }else{
                        var data : [String:AnyObject] = [:]
                        //Kegham
                        if let res = result as? [String:AnyObject]{
                            //Kegham
                            if res["email"] == nil {
                                data["email"] = res["id"]
                            } else {
                                data["email"] = res["email"]
                            }
                            //Kegham
                            print("USERNAME:\(String(describing: res["name"]))")
                            data["name"] = res["name"]
                            data["gender"] = res["gender"]
                            if let picture = res["picture"] as? NSDictionary , let pictureData = picture["data"] as? NSDictionary,let url = pictureData["url"] as? String{
                                data["image"] = url as AnyObject
                            }


                            delegate?.didFinishOperation(.FBLogin, object: User(data: data,saveToDisk: false) as AnyObject)
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```